# How would you use the API for my backend PHP?

Tags: c#, php, .net, .net-6.0

I'm a beginner in C# and I would like to create an app for Windows users in C# (frontend). On the server side I have PHP (backend).

You can imagine that I have the backend main logic in PHP on my remote linux server. The backend is accessible from the website as API (JSON structure) with a key.

So I created a simple C# form for login users. The form verifies login access from the API. That wouldn't be the main problem. As you know, there will be a problem with all the decompilers. The user could simply peek at my source code. It could modify the data in some parts of the code (the user would find the queried API URL with the key). The user could simply edit the data directly from the web API or create their own application.

How would you solve this problem?

Thanks for your help and answer.

Comment: Why is there a key?

Comment: The gist of the situation is: if the end user has your application's executable, you should assume nothing anything contained in that executable is publicly accessible. A determined and skilled person will be able to get access to them.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama The API key is used to secure access to the API from random users.

Comment: So you have a login form, but you also have an API key that's in addition to that?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Exactly, but I don't know if there is a way to encrypt this API key without the "attacker" finding out.

Comment: Do you really need the API key? Is the user being valid not enough by itself? Or could you give each user an API key too if needs be? Let's say you encrypt the API key, how would you be able to use it in your application? You couldn't, because it's encrypted. If you could use it, that would mean that the the application is able to decrypt it, which means the "attacker" can decrypt it, which brings you back to the original problem, just with an extra step.

Comment: You're right. The API key doesn't need to be there when the user is logged in. So the only way is to use some obfuscation to make the code harder to read.

Comment: If you're _that_ worried, you'd have to write the code in a language which can't be easily decompiled. But as others have said, this seems like the wrong scenario for an API key. They're normally used to stop bots etc from overwhelming your server, and to keep track of users who are otherwise not authenticated.